# Validate multiple response body nodes (values for keys) in rest assured + java

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Given:

```
  package com.company;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.hamcrest.core.Is;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "///URL";
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

        String body_content = "{\n" +
                "\t\"name\":\"Santosh\",\n" +
                "\t\"email\":\"santosh@SUMEMAIL.com\",\n" +
                "\t\"age\":30,\n" +
                "\t\"address\":{\n" +
                "\t\t\"city\":\"Bangalore\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"state\":\"karnataka\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"pinCode\":\"123\"\n" +
                "\t}\n" +
                "}";

//        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body_content);

        request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.body(body_content);

        Response response = request.post("/persons");
        System.out.println("The response is \n -------------------- \n" + response.getBody().asPrettyString());

        String myPersonId = response.path("name").toString();
        System.out.println("Its my personId = " + myPersonId);
        response.then().assertThat().body("name", Is.is("Santo1sh"));
        response.then().assertThat().body("email", Is.is("not the wright email")); // Basically I want to test multiple assertions in the same execution


    }
}
```

The response body json is:

```
{
    "personId": "c27a3364-cd93-4c10-bb58-4a17c520b54d",
    "name": "Santosh",
    "age": 30,
    "email": "santosh@gmail.com",
    "address": {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "karnataka",
        "pinCode": 560037
    }
}
```

With the above code when the last assertion is being executed, it will fail purposely, and none of the below actions will also get executed.
What I m trying to do is to test multiple values from the response's body, but not stop at first fail, how is this accomplished in rest assured?

++ Exception that is being raised:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path name doesn't match.
Expected: is "Santo1sh"
  Actual: Santosh
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for your problem.

**Solution 1:** Take advantages of assertion library has built-in `Soft assertion` function, such as [TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/testng-asserts/src/main/java/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.java) and [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions).

For example: using AssertJ

```
@Test
public void test_1(){
   ...
   SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();
   softly.assertThat(response.path("name")).isEqualTo("Santo1sh");
   softly.assertThat(response.path("email")).isEqualTo("not the wright email");
   softly.assertAll();
}
```

**Solution 2:** Deserialize response to POJO then compare objects. To define how objects equal, your POJO need to override `equals` and `hashCode` method

```
Person expect = new Person(); 

//set value for Person fields: personId, name, email ...

Person actual = JsonPath.with(res).getObject("", Person.class);

assertThat(actual, is(expect));
```

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;


@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Person{
    private String personId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Address{
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private long pinCode;
}
```